# Incompatible library version 28 and 26.1 in Build Gradle dependencies

Tags: java, android, google-api, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to make an app that uses google maps API.

But there seems to be an error in regards to libraries, that are incompatible.

It says

> 'Found versions 28.0.0 and 26.1.0 examples including
>   com.android.support:animated_vector_drawable:28.0.0  and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compact:26.1.0

Would this have an effect on calling R.id by any chance?

I've tried clean and rebuild, and invalid cache reset.
I tried to add the files as version 28.0.0 in dependency and received 2 errors:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-media-compact:28.0.0
>   Failed to resolve: com.android

```
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compact:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:animated_vector_drawable:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I would've thought that rewriting the versions would have fixed the problem but 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' is still underlined in red.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Gradle View plugin http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7150-gradle-view, I determined the issue is that play-services-location:16.0.0 has a dependency on com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0.  One technique I found to remove the warning is described here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html

which led me to add this to my gradle file:

```
implementation("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0") {
        force = true
    }
```

Comment: thank you, I was moments away from punching myself in the face

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the latest libraries update available : [link to go](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages) . And if you face again an error, you have to post the Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the dependencies (that is said to be conflicting with existing libraries) with same version no. of which it is conflicting with.